# Suspend/Hibernate not working in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, suspend, power-management, hibernate

Suspend/Hibernate is not working. Basically, when I suspend/hibernate, it just turns off my laptop screen, waits for 2-3 seconds, and turns it back on. (For hibernate, I have a large enough swap file, 64GB)

**Specs:**
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (64-bit)
Hardware Model: Dell Inc. Inspiron 3584
Processor: Intel® Core™ i3-7020U CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4
Graphics: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2F)
Gnome: 42.9
Windowing System: Wayland